# Eclipse JSP Javascript Expression Language EL parsing errors when accessing Java variable

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, jsp, el

I have a jsp in Eclipse (Kepler SR2) and it's giving me a bunch of errors on this bit of code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (Boolean(${actionBean.saveSuccess})) {
            $('#myTextField').focus();  
        }
    });
</script>
```

It seems that the parser doesn't like me using EL in the middle there with ${actionBean.saveSuccess} to get at a java variable, though the code works correctly.

Is there some way to escape things so that the parser doesn't complain?  Or possibly another way to accomplish the same result without angering the parser?

Comment: Problem w/ jQuery dollar sign and JSP dollar sign would be my guess.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var a = '${actionBean.saveSuccess}';
        if (a == true) {
            $('#myTextField').focus();  
        }
    });
</script>
```

if `${actionBean.saveSuccess}` gives you boolean value than above code helps you
try this code it will surly help you

Comment: It doesn't work correctly unless I change the if condition to (a == true).

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon.  Changing it to (a == true) only seemed to work for the false case.  I think it needs to be (a == 'true') because the var type is a string because you surrounded ${actionBean.saveSuccess} with single quotes.

Comment: Quoting the `actionBean.saveSuccess` value changes it's truthyness - this is is way too intrusive.